# Roslyn Resolved Syntax Tree without Workspaces

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to use Roslyn to create a C# code editor. I would like to get a resolved syntax tree so that I can add code completion support.

However, I cannot use Workspaces since they are broken on iOS.

I am therefore trying to hit the C# compiler directly using Compilations (is this right?). The API is simple enough, but I cannot figure out how to get member information for types.

Specifically, I would like to see a Members property of the class C that includes a reference to the fully declared D class.

However, the `INamedTypeSymbol` doesn't have any useful info attached to it.

How do I get rich type info from a CSharpCompilation?

```
var cst = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory.ParseCompilationUnit (
    "public class C { public D foo; }");
var dst = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory.ParseCompilationUnit (
    "public class D { public C bar; }");

var comp = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.
    Create ("Poo").
    AddSyntaxTrees (cst.SyntaxTree).
    AddSyntaxTrees (dst.SyntaxTree);

var classC = comp.GetSymbolsWithName (n => n == "C").FirstOrDefault (); //= C
var classD = comp.GetSymbolsWithName (n => n == "D").FirstOrDefault (); //= D

var otherClassC = comp.GetTypeByMetadataName ("C"); //= C

Console.WriteLine ("C = " + classC);
```

Comment: "However, I cannot use Workspaces since they are broken on iOS. " -- what is broken? MSBuildWorkspace specifically can't be used since MSBuild isn't yet portable, but the core bits should work just fine. We would consider any "broken"ness to be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`GetMembers()` method](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/INamespaceOrTypeSymbol.cs,23), which returns all declared members in the type.